# How to handle decimal values read from excel and store to sql - suggestions

Tags: c#, excel

I am working with excel reading and stored to db functionality in **c#**

Now I have problem to store the excel values, In my excel, some cell value is like **2.57461**, **3.576**. In SQL I have given datatype as **decimal(7,2)** so its take 2.58 But I need to store the values as it as from cell (like 2.57461, 3.576).

**Update:**
If I used decimal (18,5), then its problem for 3.576 as 3.57600, so i want to store as it as from excel.

Float it's working but I don't know that is right approach or not.

In which datatype is suitable for that or give any other solution to handle this problem - i need a idea.

Comment: predefine your database table with numeric(18,5) and insert into the table

Comment: hi @plaidDK thanks for your reply but when i give numberic(18,5) means incase my excel value come 2.572 like this means it's stored 2.57200 my accurate value is missed give anyother idea

Comment: how is 2.57200 different than 2.572? All values in the column must have the same scale so anything lower scale will have trailing zeros. The zeros is just formatting. Excel is formatting too, what you should care about is the value.

Comment: @Crowcoder  First thing is I need to capture the exact value from excel and  Excel cell can have More than 5 also possible.
So The fraction value wont be static. If 2.123456 it will round to scale 5 as 2.12346. So only I need to capture exact value from excel and store into SQL.

Comment: Do you know the max decimal places that the data may have? Supposedly Excel can use 15 max significant digits. If your integer part is always one then you can use a scale of 14. If your data is all over the place you may want to read it as a string and convert to `Decimal` in code.

Comment: @Crowcoder Anywhere In code if I want, i can convert it to decimal but that's not a scenario. Get the data from excel and do some validations and moved the validated data into SQL, Again i want to export that validated data into excel from sql using interop. So If we do your above solution then output excel will display the value with so many zeros. Thats the problem.